# Implicity constructor call

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

SLet's take this class:

```
class standardClass
{
    public:
        standardClass(int) {}

        ~standardClass() {}

        standardClass(standardClass&)  {}

        standardClass & operator=(standardClass&)
        {
            return *this; 
        } 
};

int main()
{
    standardClass stdClassObj1(1);
    standardClass stdClassObj2(stdClassObj1);
    standardClass stdClassObj3 = stdClassObj2;
    stdClassObj1 = stdClassObj2;
    stdClassObj2 = standardClass(4);
    stdClassObj2 = 4;
}
```

I am getting an error on the last assignment.

All these lines are allowed except the last one. In the last one the integer 4 does not invoke the constructor. The error says there is no assignment operator for this. I understand that. But what I'm confused is why this implicit conversion works for a new object (line 1) and not to an existing object (line 2).

I do understand that in the case of line 1, copy constructor is called to create the new AObj4. But in line 2 it invokes the assingment operator. Why cant it make a temporary object with integer 4 and invoke the assignment operator as it would do for line 3?

Comment: Is that your real code? The line which you marked `line 2` compiles for me.

Comment: Copy-construction (what happens in "line 1") and copy-assignment (what happens in "line 2") are different operations.

Comment: @remyabel I get the following error: "error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion) "

Comment: Updated with the real code.

Comment: @madu copy-assignment operator should take `const standardClass & objToCopy` (the same applies to copy-constructor)

Comment: @juanchopanza To be fair, the OP did try to clean up the code, but cleaned it up so much that the problem was gone.

Comment: I've removed the noise from your code, keeping it complete WRT the error in question.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks juan. much better. Point taken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> standardClass(standardClass &objToCopy) // copy constructor
> ```

A copy constructor should take a `const`-qualified reference, like so:

```
standardClass(const standardClass &objToCopy)
```

Same for your assignment operator: that should be

```
standardClass & operator=(const standardClass &objToCopy)
```

Non-`const`-qualified lvalue references cannot be used with temporary objects, such as the temporary object that would otherwise be created from your literal `4`.

Comment: you are right. But now I don't understand why then would the copy constructor work without the const specifier? For example stdClass stdObj = 4; would work even without the const qualifier in the copy constructor.

Comment: @madu Visual C++ has some areas in which it fails to conform to the C++ standard by default, particularly with non-`const` reference binding to temporaries which sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. On a conforming implementation, that would be diagnosed. Visual C++ has an option to disable language extensions, which you may want to experiment with. I do get an error for that if language extensions are disabled.

Comment: Thank you very much. As long as it is also supposed to fail as per standard. I thought there is some other rule pertaining to copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

You just changed the entire class. The problem is that you have:

```
   standardClass & operator=(standardClass &objToCopy)  // assignment operator
    { 
        cout << "Copy assignment operator: " << objID << endl;
        objID = objToCopy.objID; 
        return *this; 
    }
```

`4` cannot be converted to a `standardClass &`.

If you use:

```
   standardClass & operator=(standardClass const& objToCopy)
                                        // ^^^^^^
    { 
        cout << "Copy assignment operator: " << objID << endl;
        objID = objToCopy.objID; 
        return *this; 
    }
```

all will be ok.